# how to set postbackurl on linkbutton control from clientside?

Tags: asp.net

I have a server control ( linkbutton  ) on the aspx page.

For some complicated reason - I need to set the postbackurl from **client side** for this button.

Is there a way to set the postback url from client side ?

I got some reference to javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions method- but not sure how best to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the form's target using `window.document.forms[0].target='otherpage.aspx'`.
You'd also probably need to cancel event validation on the page posted to.